# Clarification on a question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have been reading this problem,

[Of any 52 integers, two can be found whose difference of squares is divisible by 100](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604635/prove-that-of-any-52-integers-two-can-always-be-found-such-that-the-difference)

That says,

> Prove that of any 52 integers, two can always be found such that the
>   difference of their squares is divisible by 100.

Now, in my understanding, it says, **any 52 integers**.

So I could just choose 0 and 100, from a random set of integers right?

100^2 - 0^2 = 10000 which is devisible by 100.

What I am not getting here? I read the answers but I still cant figure out what exactly the problem is asking.

Basically I am trying to understand the first answer:

> Look at your 52 integers mod 100. Look at the pairs of additive
>   inverses (0,0), (1,99), (2,98), etc. There are 51 such pairs. Since we
>   have 52 integers, two of them must belong to a pair (x,−x). Then
>   x^2−(−x^)2=0(mod100), so that the difference of their squares is
>   divisible by 100.

So he creates a set, and in that set he has sets of cardinality 2.
Then he says Since we

> have 52 integers, two of them must belong to a pair (x,−x).

This is what I dont get. The integers can be (4, -9) or (15, 40) who says they need to be additive inverses. He just created a new set and made up some rules. I dont get it

Comment: The key is _any_ $52$ (pairwise disjoint) integers. You cannot tell if $0$ or $100$ are chosen at all.

Comment: It only says that two numbers can always be found, given any 52 integers. You have solved the problem only for a set containing 0 and 100. So take this set for example: $S=\{ 10^9+k \mid k=1,\ldots 52\}$.

Comment: well is he referring to all the integers? so your set is invalid

Comment: One might reword the question as the following "Given a set $A\subset\mathbb{Z}$ whose cardinality is $52$, show that there exist $a,b\in A$ such that $100\mid a^2-b^2$." Does that help clear things up? You have to show it holds for **all** such $A$.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "You have to show it holds for all such A", you mean that for every 2 random number I just pick up ?

Comment: No, for every set of $52$ integers. You have to show it holds for $\{1,\ldots ,52\}$ and for $\{2,4,6,\ldots, 104\}$ and for $\{1001,1002,1003,\ldots,1052\}$ and for any other set of integers which have $52$ distinct elements. Show that each of them has two elements which have the square difference property.

Comment: I have edited My question. Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

The given set of integers may not contain $0$ nor $100$. Hence your proof is not valid...

Comment: what? Who says that? What if my set is S = { -2 .. 100 } ?

Comment: In that case your proof is correct. But you have infinitely many other possibilities to check. When one say "prove that *any* set ..." you must consider every possibility. Otherwise one would say "prove that for *some* set ..."