# Show that the sum or difference of $a_i$ and $a_j$ from a set of seven distinct integers is divisible by 10

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I know this is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594426/show-that-any-set-of-7-distinct-integers-includes-two-integers-x-and-y-such), but I don't understand the top answer at all. How does squaring $a$ show what we're supposed to show?

Here's my intuition on how to prove this: 
$a_i$ and $a_j$ can be decomposed as a sum of multiples of powers of $10$ since we're working in base $10$. When we add or subtract $a_i$ and $a_j$ from each other we want to show that their remainder is zero using the pigeonhole principle.

Is this a correct way of looking at it?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that if reduced mod 10 there can be repeats. [so the reduced numbers might not be distinct] Also does it mean there is a sum div by 10 *and also* a difference div by 10, or does it mean *either* a sum div by 10 *or* a difference div by 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The idea behind that proof** is that 
$$0=a_i^2-a_j^2 =(a_i-a_j)(a_i+a_j) \pmod{10}$$

Then at least one of $(a_i-a_j),(a_i+a_j)$ is divisible by $2$ and at least one is divisible by $5$. Now show that $(a_i-a_j)$ and $(a_i+a_j) $ have the same parity.

**Your idea** also works:

Split the seven numbers among the following $6$ boxes:

$$\{ 1,9 \pmod{10} \} ; \{ 2,8 \pmod{10} \} ; \{ 3,7 \pmod{10} \} \\ \{ 4,6 \pmod{10} \} ; \{ 5 \pmod{10} \} ; \{ 0 \pmod{10} \}$$

Then at least one box contains two numbers. If the two numbers in the same box are congruent $\pmod{10}$, then their difference is divisible by $10$. Otherwise, their sum is divisible by 10.

Comment: Why is the difference of squares congruent to 0 (mod 10)?

Comment: @user2965071 That's exactly what the answer you posted shows: that there exists some $i,j$ such that $$a_i^2 \equiv a_j^2 \pmod{10}$$